# How to count many categorical values per row?

Tags: r, count, row

I have this data frame:

```
IDSurvey = c(12234,23456,12356)
Q1 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes")
Q2 = rep("No",3)
Q3 = rep("Yes", 3)
D = data.frame(IDSurvey, Q1, Q2, Q3)
```

And I hope your help to find this answer.

```
IDSurvey  Q1 Q2  Q3 NunmberOfYes NumberOfNo
    12234 Yes No Yes  2            1 
    23456  No No Yes  1            2 
    12356 Yes No Yes  2            1
```

Thank you very much for your help and patience. Greetings!

Comment: What sort of things have you already tried? Do you get some sort of error that is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: @RAB OP wants row level count of Yes and No ... Currently it is just forming a frame with IDSurvey and  Q1,Q2, and Q3. Aggregation columns are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Base R

```
IDSurvey = c(12234,23456,12356)
Q1 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes")
Q2 = rep("No",3)
Q3 = rep("Yes", 3)
D = data.frame(IDSurvey, Q1, Q2, Q3)
str(D)
```

solution

```
D$yes <- rowSums(D == "Yes",na.rm=TRUE)
D$No <-  rowSums(D == "No",na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: The warning(s) is(are) due to different factor levels. You may need to refactor.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
D %>% 
  gather(key,value,-IDSurvey) %>% 
with(table(IDSurvey,value))
```

Or this:

```
D %>% 
  gather(key,value,-IDSurvey) %>% 
  group_by(IDSurvey) %>% 
  count(value) %>% 
  spread(value,n)
```